# Can you onblur a set of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a set of checkboxes, and validation such that at least one of those checkboxes need to be checked on submit.  But I want to be able to set a validation error if the user blurs out of the set of checkboxes.  The problem is that if I do a blur for the last one it doesn't work because they could be shift-tabbing to the second from last checkbox.  I've tried to but the onblur in the fieldset tag, but that didn't trigger a blur at all.  Is this just a limitation that can't be overcome with plain html and vanilla JS?

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example (code snippet  )

Comment: You may want to look into using CSS to create your own checkboxes? Look up "pure CSS checkboxes" and there is a lot you can do with CSS3 selectors. Also, if you want to incorporate validation with JS you could control the visuals around selected/valid, selected/invalid, and blurred, but even that you can do with some HTML5 + CSS3.

Comment: Unsure why they would need to recreate a checkbox @NeilGuyLindberg....

Comment: So your idea will work if they use a keyboard to navigate, but if they are a mouse user is it going to help? For your idea, you can look at what the active element is and determine if it is outside of the group.

Comment: @epascarello it is not recreating. It is a method of hiding the checkbox element itself, using CSS to draw your own, and using psuedo selectors. You'd have to look up "pure CSS checkboxes" for any further knowledge as it is not a small process to explain.

Comment: @NeilGuyLindberg what is hiding it going to help with blur and validation?

Comment: @epascarello I tried creating a function that looks at the active element and if it's not  a checkbox, it will issue/remove the warning.  However, when I tab through, the active element is just being reported as the body of the document for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on epascarello's suggestion I was able to create a function that provided similar functionality to the one provided. I have an error span that's underneath the checkboxes.  I wanted behavior that would immediately remove that if any checkbox was checked, but only add the error span if the user blurred out of the entire set of checkboxes. Note that there is only one fieldset on this page, and the error span has an specific id I could reference.  Here's the function that I got working:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach((elem) => {
            elem.addEventListener("blur", function (event) {
                var errorSpan = document.getElementById("checkboxesErrorSpan");
                var isValid = document.querySelector("fieldset").querySelectorAll("input:checked").length > 0;
                if (isValid) {
                    if ((errorSpan.style.display == "inline")) {
                        errorSpan.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (event.relatedTarget.type != "checkbox") {
                        if ((errorSpan.style.display == "none")) {
                            errorSpan.style.display = "inline";
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at what the next element that is focused is and determine if they are under the same grouping.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener("blur", function (event) {
    const nextElem = event.relatedTarget;
    const fieldSet = elem.closest('fieldset');
    const isValid = fieldSet.querySelector("input:checked") !== null;
    if (nextElem?.closest('fieldset') !== fieldSet) {
        fieldSet.classList.toggle("error", !isValid);
    } else if (isValid) {
        fieldSet.classList.remove("error");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Pizza One</legend>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x1-1" id="x1-1">
    <label for="x1-1">Cheese</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x1-2" id="x1-2">
    <label for="x1-2">Peppers</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x1-3" id="x1-3">
    <label for="x1=3">Mushrooms</label>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Pizza Two</legend>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x2-1" id="x2-1">
    <label for="x2-1">Cheese</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x2-2" id="x2-2">
    <label for="x2-2">Peppers</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x2-3" id="x2-3">
    <label for="x2-3">Mushrooms</label>

  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Adding in a trick to use HTML5 validation

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
    const nextElem = event.relatedTarget;
    const fieldSet = elem.closest('fieldset');
    const isValid = fieldSet.querySelector("input:checked") !== null;
    if (nextElem?.closest('fieldset') !== fieldSet) {
      fieldSet.classList.toggle("error", !isValid);
    }
  });

  elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    const fieldSet = elem.closest('fieldset');
    const isValid = fieldSet.querySelector("input:checked") !== null;
    if (isValid) {
      fieldSet.classList.remove("error");
      fieldSet.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((cb) => {
        cb.removeAttribute("required");
      });
    } else {
      fieldSet.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((cb) => {
        cb.setAttribute("required", "required");
      });
    }
  });

  const changeEvt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  changeEvt.initEvent("change", false, true);
  elem.dispatchEvent(changeEvt);
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Pizza One</legend>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x1-1" id="x1-1">
    <label for="x1-1">Cheese</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x1-2" id="x1-2">
    <label for="x1-2">Peppers</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x1-3" id="x1-3">
    <label for="x1=3">Mushrooms</label>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Pizza Two</legend>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x2-1" id="x2-1">
    <label for="x2-1">Cheese</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x2-2" id="x2-2">
    <label for="x2-2">Peppers</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="x2-3" id="x2-3">
    <label for="x2-3">Mushrooms</label>

  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I used some of them to construct a function that was a bit more specific to my situation.  Note that your fieldSet.querySelector("input:checked") !== null; didn't work for me, I had to use document.querySelector("fieldset").querySelectorAll("input:checked").length.